# vb.net if else logic flow error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, logic

I am debugging some code in an ASP.net web application project.

I have an If/Else statement nested in a Try/Catch block. Whenever an error occurs within the If block, rather than immediately jumping into the Catch block, it falls into the Else block.

I have stepped through the code repeatedly to witness this happening. When I throw an exception within the if block, I would expect logic to flow into the catch block, and I would never expect to see the if block get hit, and then the else block get hit, that seems to completely defeat the purpose of the if/else logic.

Here is the code in question:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    LoadDocument()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadDocument()
    Dim taDocuments As New SecureTableAdapters.IndividualDocumentsTableAdapter
    Dim dtDocuments As New Secure.IndividualDocumentsDataTable
    Dim iDocumentID As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("iDocumentID"))
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim isMac As Boolean = clsApplication.isMac(Request.Browser.Platform)
    Dim bDownloaded As Boolean = False

    Try
        If taDocuments.FillBy_IndividualDocumentID(dtDocuments, iDocumentID) > 0 Then
            Dim oRow As Secure.IndividualDocumentsRow = dtDocuments.Rows(0)
            sFileName = "Statement-" & oRow.sFileNumber & ".pdf"

            If oRow.sDocumentName.ToUpper.Contains("LEDES") Or oRow.sDocumentName.ToUpper.Contains("TEXT") Then
                sFileName = sFileName.Replace("pdf", "txt")
            End If

            Dim b As Byte() = Nothing

            If oRow.IsbExtractedNull = False AndAlso oRow.bExtracted Then

                Dim sHost As String = "206.220.201.175"
                Dim sPath As String = String.Format("/Legacy/{0}/{1}/{2}.pdf", oRow.iFirmID.ToString, "Individuals", oRow.iIndividualDocumentID.ToString)
                b = DownloadDocument(sHost, sPath)

                If b Is Nothing Then
                    'When this line is hit, logic jumps to the else block with the comment below
                    Throw New Exception("FTP Download Failed")
                Else
                    bDownloaded = True
                End If
            Else
                bDownloaded = False
            End If

            If bDownloaded = False Then
                b = getImage(iDocumentID, "oPDF", "iIndividualDocumentID", "tblIndividualDocuments")
                If b Is Nothing Then
                    Throw New Exception
                End If
            End If

            If isMac Then
                Response.ContentType = "application/x-macbinary"
            Else
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            End If

            Response.Expires = 0
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & sFileName & """")
            Response.BinaryWrite(b)
        Else
            '--->When the exception occurs, logic jumps to this else block
            Throw New Exception
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Sorry, that statement could not be located. Please try again, or call us at xxx.xxx.xxxx for further information.")
        clsApplication.EmailError("An error occurred downloading a statement: " & vbCrLf & ex.Source & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)

    End Try

End Sub
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you have optimizations turned off for Debugging?

Comment: RBarryYoung - No, and this turned out to be the problem. I had full debugging enabled and also had Enabled Optimizations. I read that enabling this option can cause difficulty debugging, but I had no idea that it could alter fundamental language logic flow. If it was just something that effected debugging that'd be one thing, but I found that it occurs when published as well. So it would seem that enabling optimizations is extremely dangerous.

Comment: Good job RBarryYoung.  You should post this as the answer and get full credit :)  I'm glad to hear that the problem is resolved and I learned something new :)

Comment: Yeah, this should be posted as the answer. I actually didn't even see this until I tried to post my own answer, and it wouldn't allow me to post it because it hasn't been 8 hours since I first asked.

Comment: @Derek I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the debugger with Optimizations still turned on.  This can cause the Step Traceing to act in seemingly illogical and even impossible ways.  This is caused because after the optimizer moves the code and variables around and consolidates different statements, there is no longer a simple or straight-forward relationship between the lines of source-code and the executable instructions.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. That being said, it should be noted that it was not just appearing like the code in the else block was being hit when I was in the debugger, it was actually executing those lines of code. When I published that code to the server, without a debugger attached, those lines were still getting hit. So it would seem that the optimizations are incredibly dangerous as they can cause your code to execute incorrectly if a PDB is present.

Comment: @Josh I've never heard of the external behavior (other than performance) being affected by the optimizations setting.  If true, then this is definitely a VS.net bug and should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: I will have to perform some additional tests to be sure that my conclusion is accurate, and will post back here the results.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the code you're debugging against might be out of sync with the code that's executing. Try rebuilding the whole solution.

Comment: Did that. Also performed a clean, and manually deleted the bin and obj folders. Still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably mistaken:

Try the following in simple vb .net winforms program.

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Try
         Dim doIt As Boolean = True
         If doIt Then
            Throw New Exception("throwing that stuff")
         Else
            MsgBox("in here - how did that happen?")

         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(String.Format("That makes sense.  Exception is: {0}", ex))
      End Try


   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am certainly not mistaken. Aside from the fact that I've been developing with Visual Studio for 15 years, I'm watching it happen. Kind of hard to mistake the current line jumping from the throw line to the else block. I can record a screencast of it happening if that would help you believe that what I am saying is happening is in fact happening.

Comment: I upvoted James Johnson's reply.  What you are seeing can't really be happening.  At least I really don't think so.

Comment: Also, this is in a Web Application, not a winforms applications.

Comment: I don't think the basic rules of try/catch should be different for a web application.  It is interesting why you would be seeing this.

Comment: "What you are seeing can't really be happening." - Well it is happening. I agree that it shouldn't be happening and should not even be remotely possible, but it is most definitely happening. My code is not out of synch, I can change it and watch the new code get executed/debugged. I know the symptoms when the code is out of synch, and I have been able to prove that this is not the case.

Comment: OK.  Next logical step is to verify that you can make a change in the code so you can verify that you are running the correct code.  Is there any way you can log or show a message box or do something to show that the code you are changing matches what is running?  Pretty much everyone here is saying that you are not seeing what you ARE seeing, so something crazy is going on.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I can change it and watch the new code get executed, so I know it's not out of sync. I put in a message box to prove that it was in fact getting hit. If the code was out of sync, new code that I write wouldn't get hit, I've seen that happen before, so it was the first thing I checked.